# How to keep gridlines on but turn ytick off in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, charts

I am trying to put grid lines on my plot but turn off the numbered markers on the axis.

I first turn on the grid lines using:

```
grid on;
```

However when I get rid of the markers using

```
set(gca,'YTick',[]); % Get rid of markers
```

The y grid turns off! How do I get it to stay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more elegant solution but you could set the tick labels to empty strings.

```
 set(gca, 'YTickLabel', [])
```

This way the tick marks are still there.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

You have to use the following to turn off the label:

```
set(gca,'yticklabel',[])
```